# error: ‘struct arphdr’ has no member named ‘ar_sha’

Tags: c++, c, struct

I'm creating my own ARP eader with below shown code, however this code ain't working, I get error message as ‘struct arphdr’ has no member named ‘ar_sha’, ar_spa, ar_tha, ar_tpa. I've checked net/if_arp.h, these members are part of struct arphdr. Why i'm unable to use them?? Please assist.

```
  arp.ar_hrd=htons(ARPHRD_ETHER);
  arp.ar_pro=htons(ETHERTYPE_IP);
  arp.ar_hln=6;
  arp.ar_pln=4;
  arp.ar_op=htons(ARPOP_REQUEST);
  arp.ar_sha=ether_aton("ss:ss:ss:ss:ss:ss");
  arp.ar_spa=inet_addr("192:168:32:128");
  arp.ar_tha=ether_aton("ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff");
  arp.arp_tpa=inet_addr("192.168.32.1");
```

Comment: `#if 0` implies it is not compiled in.

Comment: Would you mind telling us the envorinment you are observing this in.  Networking is not part of Standard-C. This is not a guessing game.

Comment: This is RHEL 6.6, gcc version 4.4.7. Agreed that #if 0, it will not compile, the question is, how this will be achieved then???

Comment: How is arp declared? How and where is the struct declared that seems to be the type of arp?

Comment: int main()
{
  struct arphdr arp;
  arp.ar_hrd=htons(ARPHRD_ETHER);
  arp.ar_pro=htons(ETHERTYPE_IP);
  arp.ar_hln=6;
  arp.ar_pln=4;
  arp.ar_op=htons(ARPOP_REQUEST);
  arp.ar_sha=ether_aton("ss:ss:ss:ss:ss:ss");
  arp.ar_spa=inet_addr("192:168:32:128");
  arp.ar_tha=ether_aton("ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff");
  arp.arp_tpa=inet_addr("192.168.32.1");

  ............
  ............
  return 0;
}